# How to use XPATH expression to optimize the number of for loops?

Tags: java, xpath

Hi I have an XML file which contains the following

```
    <Attribute ID="pdm_atr_alu_index" MultiValued="false" ProductMode="Normal" FullTextIndexed="false" ExternallyMaintained="true" Derived="false" Mandatory="false">
      <Name QualifierID="std.lang.all">aluminium index</Name>
      <Validation BaseType="text" MinValue="" MaxValue="" MaxLength="100" InputMask=""/>
      <DimensionLink DimensionID="Country"/>
      <MetaData>
        <Value AttributeID="DisplaySequence">92</Value>
        <ValueGroup AttributeID="SapCommerceExport">
          <Value ID="Y" LOVQualifierID="en-UK">Yes</Value>
          <Value ID="Y" LOVQualifierID="std.lang.all">Yes</Value>
        </ValueGroup>
        <Value ID="automatically" AttributeID="TechnicalDataTableUpdate">automatically</Value>
        <ValueGroup AttributeID="pdm_atr_top5_yes_display_name">
          <Value Derived="true" DerivedContextID="con_RU-ru">aluminium index</Value>
          <Value Derived="true" DerivedContextID="con_RU-en">aluminium index</Value>
        </ValueGroup>
        <ValueGroup AttributeID="pdm_atr_web_display_name_calc">
          <Value Derived="true" DerivedContextID="con_RU-en">aluminium index</Value>
          <Value Derived="true" DerivedContextID="con_RU-ru">aluminium index</Value>
        </ValueGroup>
      </MetaData>
      <AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="pdm_agr_export_sapcommerce"/>
      <AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="pdm_agr_import"/>
      <AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="pdm_agr_general_information"/>
      <UserTypeLink UserTypeID="pdm_obj_sellable_article"/>
    </Attribute>
.....
```

I am trying to extract the ID from Attribute tag and value of AttributeGroupID from AttributeGroupLink tag as follows

```
XPathExpression xpAttribute =
          xpath.compile("//STEP-ProductInformation/AttributeList/Attribute");
      XPathExpression xpAttributeGroupLink = xpath.compile("AttributeGroupLink");
      int l = 0;

      NodeList attributes = (NodeList) xpAttribute.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

      for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {

        Element attribute = (Element) attributes.item(i);
        NodeList values =
            (NodeList) xpAttributeGroupLink.evaluate(attribute, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int j = 0; j < values.getLength(); j++) {
          NamedNodeMap attr = values.item(j).getAttributes();
          String attributeGroupID = attr.item(0).getNodeValue();
          System.out.println(attributeGroupID);
          if (hashMap.containsKey(attributeGroupID)) {
            HashSet<String> attributeIDExisting = hashMap.get(attributeGroupID);
            attributeIDExisting.add(attribute.getAttribute("ID"));
```

Is there a possibility to extract the Attribute IDs as groups and use a single for loop to acheive the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to query all attributes in a single xpath expression and iterate over them as

```
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIS;
        fileIS = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/tmp/tmp.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document xmlDocument;
        xmlDocument = builder.parse(fileIS);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression01 = "//Attribute/@ID";
        String expression02 = "//Attribute/AttributeGroupLink/@AttributeGroupID";
        String expression = String.format("%s | %s", expression01, expression02);
        NodeList nodeList =(NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
                System.out.println(currentNode.getNodeName() + ": " + currentNode.getTextContent());
            }
        }
    } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException | XPathExpressionException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result:

```
ID: pdm_atr_alu_index
AttributeGroupID: pdm_agr_export_sapcommerce
AttributeGroupID: pdm_agr_import
AttributeGroupID: pdm_agr_general_information
```